# Android API Level 8 App Install Location Feature

Tags: android

Does this feature allow you to upload an APK larger than 25MB?  For example a 32MB apk?

Comment: How on earth is your app that big?!

Comment: you should put your sound files as a separate application which acts as a plugin for your application, and compress them as much as you can.

Comment: @Pentium10 Are you saying there will not be a 25MB file size limit on the plugin?  The sounds have been compressed as much as possible.

Comment: Have you compressed your sounds? You should use ogg or mp3 instead of wav. Also you could have your program download the necessary sounds from a server on the first run of the app if it is too big.

Comment: I don't know the app size limit, but when I install your app it should not be that big, the app should tell me if I want the sounds, to download this additional pack.

Comment: @stealthcopter I'm not using wav, I just have alot of mp3 files.  Thanks, I've got the Downloader code from Google Code, but will probably not go that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not.